# Spring Batch continuous integration testing

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

We have a Spring Batch application. Together with the ability to run the application, we also have some lightweight test classes which allow us to run each job by itself, and to perform assertions after the job is completed.

That’s fine for running tests locally.
However, can anyone advise on what are considered best practices for defining tests to run in a continuous integration environment, such as TeamCity.

Should tests which, for instance, setup or clear down a database, or write to a queue or a file, be run as part of continuous integration?
Should these resources be mocked, and if so are there any classes Spring Batch has to assist with this?

Or, is the above overkill? The alternative would be for the continuous integration only to run tests for domain specific logic we have written, such as processors.

A similar question is relevant for testing Spring Integration applications using continuous integration.

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can use `in-memory` solutions: embedded database, only simple managers. And close and destroy those resources in the end of test. The [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) provides enough `AutoCofiguration` option for that.

Comment: Thanks Artem. What about writing to files, queues?

Comment: `files` can be based on the JUnit `TemporaryFolder`. `queues` are in-memory by default (or can be based on that embedded DB) and they are just in the `applicationContext` scope.